# How to integrate Hive (avro tables) with Schema Registry?

Tags: hive, registry, schema, avro

Hive provides two table properties allowing to define Avro schema: `avro.schema.literal` and `avro.schema.url`, where the former can specify a hdfs path or http endpoint serving the schema. I'd like to use [Schema Registry](http://docs.confluent.io/current/schema-registry/docs/intro.html) as my schema service, but the problem is its [endpoints](http://docs.confluent.io/current/schema-registry/docs/api.html) return schema wrapped in a bigger json object:

Request:

```
GET /schemas/ids/1
```

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/vnd.schemaregistry.v1+json

{
  "schema": "{\"type\": \"string\"}"
}
```

Request:

```
GET /subjects/test/versions/1
```

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/vnd.schemaregistry.v1+json

{
  "name": "test",
  "version": 1,
  "schema": "{\"type\": \"string\"}"
}
```

The above responses cannot be parsed by Hive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My idea so far is to put a proxy service in front of Schema Registry (serving pure avro schemas) and scale it with HAProxy. Schema Registry itself seems to have [scalable architecture](http://docs.confluent.io/current/schema-registry/docs/design.html) for reads. To be honest I don't understand the paragraph about `avro.schema.url` property in [AvroSerDe hive documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/AvroSerDe):

> Specifies a URL to access the schema from. For http schemas, this
>   works for testing and small-scale clusters, but as the schema will be
>   accessed at least once from each task in the job, this can quickly
>   turn the job into a DDOS attack against the URL provider (a web
>   server, for instance). Use caution when using this parameter for
>   anything other than testing.

I think that my proposal is a viable solution.

Having schemas in centralised repo allows for schema evolution and checking backward/forward compatibility, hence it's better than defining hdfs path, which is recommended in AvroSerDe docs.

Comment: *can quickly turn the job into a DDOS attack* -- This should be obvious. Each map tasks will need to perform a GET request against the Schema registry. In a large cluster, you have hundreds of clients hitting the same schema url. Having the schema file on disk is less of a bottleneck

Answer (score 3):

I'm looking to do the same thing you are.  I logged https://github.com/confluentinc/schema-registry/issues/629 for an enhancement to the schema registry to make this easy.  Hopefully the project is receptive to this idea.  It seems it should be a simple enhancement to implement.

Comment: Cool, I hope they will add such endpoints to schema registry API

Comment: Thanks Ben. It seems this issue has been resolved by confluent. https://docs.confluent.io/current/schema-registry/develop/api.html#get--subjects-(string-%20subject)-versions-(versionId-%20version)-schema